# calling program from another program using bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, windows-runtime

I have a problem, i want to run my program with another program with a parameter. in first program, this is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting cmd main");
    String runPath = args[0];
    String path = args[1];
    String flagname = args[2];
    String lockPath = args[3];
    String tampung = args[4];
    
    String command = "cmd.exe "
            + "/C"
            + " cd C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR"
            +" && rar a -n "+runPath+tampung+".zip "
            + path+ flagname    + " -p"+tampung
            + "\n && rar a -n "+lockPath+tampung+".zip "
            + path+ flagname + " -p"+tampung;

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

when i try to run in cmd, the program i compiled without any errors. But when i try to call from another program, the program is running but the Runtime not give any result. Here the second program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String runPath = "E:\\Sementara\\DEVELOPMENT\\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\\FLAG\\RUN\\";
    String path = "E:\\Sementara\\DEVELOPMENT\\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\\FLAG\\";
    String flagname = "CMDcommand.txt";
    String lockPath ="E:\\Sementara\\DEVELOPMENT\\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\\FLAG\\RUN\\LOCK\\";
    String tampung = "testing";
    String cmd = "C:\\ProgramCmd\\Start.bat" + " " + runPath + " " + path + " "+ flagname + " " + lockPath + " " + tampung;
    
    String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/c", cmd };                                            
    System.out.println("Command: " + cmd);

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line="";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        process.waitFor();  
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For the .bat in the first program, i use this:

```
java CmdMain %1 %2 %3 %4 %5
```

When i try to running the program, here the result:

> Command: C:\ProgramCmd\Start.bat E:\Sementara\DEVELOPMENT\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\FLAG\RUN\ E:\Sementara\DEVELOPMENT\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\FLAG\ CMDcommand.txt E:\Sementara\DEVELOPMENT\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\FLAG\RUN\LOCK\ testing
>
> C:\Users\Agung Rizkiono\Documents\Development\Workspace2\testing2>java CmdMain E:\Sementara\DEVELOPMENT\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\FLAG\RUN\ E:\Sementara\DEVELOPMENT\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\FLAG\ CMDcommand.txt E:\Sementara\DEVELOPMENT\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\FLAG\RUN\LOCK\ testing

How can i try to fix the second program?

Comment: Are you sure that you can pass that much stuff to `cmd.exe` in your first program?  I've never tried that.  I would start by making sure the first program works, without the second program, using hardcoded values for the parameters instead of `args[0]` and so on.  It could be that trying to use `cmd.exe` to execute multiple commands just doesn't work.  But like I said, I've never tried it.

Comment: it works, when i try to give parameters like "java CmdMain E:\Sementara\DEVELOPMENT\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\FLAG\RUN\ E:\Sementara\DEVELOPMENT\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\FLAG\ CMDcommand.txt E:\Sementara\DEVELOPMENT\SpoolPFileLapBulTBEListener\FLAG\RUN\LOCK\ testing" in cmd, the program run perfectly. when i try to called from another program, the program is running without go to catch statement

Comment: In that case, I don't know...  In your second program, you're mixing a `String[]` and a `String` to create your process.  Maybe it's possible that could confuse the interpreter, which might try to interpret the entire `cmd` as the name of an executable, instead of splitting it up?  Try making `command` an array of 8 strings, instead of 3.

Comment: as i know, there is not effected when the program have String[] in main program in the second program as long as i dont give to the another program the parameter. and i don't really get it. what is mean to try making command an array of 8 string instead of 3?

Comment: sorry, but i dont get it, can you explain what you mean?, because i try to run my first program with `java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .\bin\ CmdMain (parameter) (parameter2) (parameter3) (parameter4) (parameter5)` and the program running and it ziping my file. But when i try to call the first program in the second program, i not run to the catch statement at all, it run successfully, but it not zipping my file.

Comment: Here's what I mean by an array of 8 strings instead of 3: the 8 strings are `"cmd.exe"`, `"/c"`, `"C:\\ProgramCmd\\Start.bat"`, `runPath`, `path`, `flagname`, `lockPath`, `tampung`.  That is, don't concatenate the last 6 parameters into one big string.  The question "is a space part of an argument, or a separator between arguments", is a tricky one, and you don't always know how something like  `exec()` handles it.  So sometimes you have to try different things to find out which one works.